# Enable ISO/IEC 14443 Type A in omnikey 5422

Tags: nfc, smartcard, contactless-smartcard, omnikey

I disabled ISO/IEC 14443 Type A from Omnikey workbench without knowing. Then smart card reader is not reading nfc cards. Configuration for mac os and hid omnikey workbench 2.3.

I searched from some resources and it says to fix with pcsc_control but there is no pcsc_control.